# global variable is not accessible in firebase function

Tags: javascript, firebase

I declared a global array in index.js (firebase function). Once the code is deployed, this array is filled from firebase data.
I have two functions, in the first one (onTW) i made some changes to the array, and i'm just displaying it in the other function(onRemoveTW). The problem is I'm getting an empty array in the second function.
Here's my code.

```
    var TWArray = [];
    TWRef.once('value', function (snapshot) {
snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
    var name=childSnapshot.key;
    var users = {};
    var userNbr = 0;
    TWRef.child(name).child('rm').once('value', function (snapshot2) {
        snapshot2.forEach(function(childSnapshot2) {
            userNbr++;
            if(childSnapshot2.key=='a'){
                users.a = childSnapshot2.val();
            }
            if(childSnapshot2.key=='b'){
                users.b = childSnapshot2.val();
            }
            if(childSnapshot2.key=='c'){
                users.c = childSnapshot2.val();
            }
            if(childSnapshot2.key=='d'){
                users.d = childSnapshot2.val();
            }
        })
        TWArray.push({
            rmName:name,
            users:users,
            userNbr:userNbr
        });
    })

})
    })
    exports.onTW = functions.database
    .ref('/Orders/TW/{requestId}')
    .onWrite(event => {
const userKey = event.data.key;
const post = event.data.val();
 if (post != null) {
    var users={};
            users.a=userKey;
            TWArray.push({
                rmName:userKey,
                users:users,
                userNbr:1
            });
            console.log(TWArray);
            console.log("TWArray.length : "+TWArray.length);
     }
    });
     exports.onRemoveTW = functions.database
     .ref('/Orders/RemoveTW/{requestId}')
    .onWrite(event => {
const userKey = event.data.key;
const post = event.data.val();
if (post != null) {

    console.log("TWArray.length : "+TWArray.length);
}
    })
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

You cannot share data between functions by writing to global variables when using *firebase-functions*, because they intended to be stateless. As such, this functionality is not supported.

What you can do is write your data to *firebase-database* instead.